# PayPal SetExpressCheckout error

Tags: php, paypal

I am having some issues with `SetExpressCheckout` at PayPal. I am trying to set a new express checkout with an item that costs 11.96 EUR (including VAT 21%). Howevere, PayPal says that the amounts in the cart don't match the order. Here is the request:

```
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
[SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 11.96
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 9.88
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 2.08
[L_BILLINGTYPE0] => MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement
[BILLINGTYPE] => MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement
[L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0] => Some description here
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT0] => 9.88
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => 011213
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Description here
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 2.08
[L_PAYMENTTYPE0] => ANY
```

ANd here is then response from PayPal:

> ```
> [ACK] => Failure
> [VERSION] => 72.0
> [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
> [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
> [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
> [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
> ```

Am i missing something here ? I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue with the following request:

```
[METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
[NOSHIPPING] => 1
[ALLOWNOTE] => 1
[LOCALECODE] => IT
[PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
[CHANNELTYPE] => Merchant
[REQCONFIRMSHIPPING] => 0
[CALLBACKVERSION] => 72.0
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
[SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 14.33
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 11.84
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 2.49
[L_BILLINGTYPE0] => MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement
[BILLINGTYPE] => MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement
[L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0] => Billing agreement description
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 11.84
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Item name
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Item description
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 2.49
[L_PAYMENTTYPE0] => ANY
```

The prices are different because I actually changed them (they don't affect the final result though). Basicly I was missing some fields (such as `[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0]` while sending `[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT0]`, which shouldn't be the case.